# ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED - PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, ssl

The script below works perfectly when my site is without SSL, that is, with the domain http://www.dominio.com.br, but when I activate SSL for the site, it will be like https://www.dominio.com.br, Google Chrome displays the error "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED". But in firefox the error does not occur.

```
<?php

function redirecionaVariaveisCF7() {
?>
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '4' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
        for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
            if ( 'nome' == inputs[i].name ) {
                var nome = inputs[i].value;
            }
            if ( 'email' == inputs[i].name ) {
                var email = inputs[i].value;
            }
        }
        window.location.href = 'testes/wp_01/teste-sucesso/?nome='+nome+'&email='+email;
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirecionaVariaveisCF7' );

add_action( 'the_content', 'exibeVariaveisCF7' );

function exibeVariaveisCF7($cf7_exibe_mensagem_conteudo) {

    if(is_page('teste-sucesso')){
        $nome = htmlspecialchars($_GET["nome"]);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_GET["email"]);

        ?><script>
function cont(){
   var conteudo = document.getElementById('boxImpressaoDisponivel').innerHTML;
   tela_impressao = window.open('https://www.meudominio.com.br');
   tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
   tela_impressao.window.print();
   tela_impressao.window.close();
}
</script><?php

        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt = "<div class='container' id='boxImpressaoDisponivel'> <br> <center><img src='https://www.meudominio.com.br/testes/wp_01/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/logo.png' width='120'></center> <br><br><br>";

        if ($nome != NULL){
            $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "<b>Nome:</b> " . $nome  ."<br>";
        }

        if ($email != NULL){
            $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "<b>E-mail:</b> " . $email  ."<br>";
        }

        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "</div>";

        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "<div class='container'>";        
        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "<input type='button' onclick='cont();' value='Imprimir'>";
        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "</div>";

    }

    $cf7_exibe_mensagem_resultado = $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt . $cf7_exibe_mensagem_conteudo;

    return $cf7_exibe_mensagem_resultado;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a browser to go to the address using https, you may find the cert is not correct.

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ is great for checking the SSL impementation.

Comment: Also check chromes devtools the console will likely yield something useful to your question if you cannot resolve it yourself from the information given.

Comment: PD of [Port 443 works but not https](//stackoverflow.com/q/39524832)

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome have strange behavior when switching between http/https. It has some kind of cache I think. There's nothing wrong with your PHP-script if it works in FF. So give Chrome some time...